# Issues with incoming MMS getting stuck

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, mms

I have an issue with MMS messages getting stuck.
I'm not sure if this is an Android issue (standard, custom rom, rooted, ect) or a carrier one.

I'll have backed up MMS messages with no indication, but if I toggle data off for ~10 seconds and then back on, they ALL come in. Sometimes over a day's worth. I've done this and gotten bombarded with upwards of 30+ pictures, group chat, etc all of which had no indication that they were there at all.

I'm on a 6.0.1 CM based Rom.
I'm rooted (systemless with Magisk)
I have Xposed installed
My phone is a Oneplus 3T

Comment: Seems likely to be a ROM issue.